# Deleting indexedDB database doesn't reduce Internet.edb size

Tags: internet-explorer-11, indexeddb

I have got an application that I am storing some images in the indexedDB.
In IE11 I seem to get the following problem:
When I create a database the size of the Interner.edb (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Indexed DB) file where the database gets stored increases obviously but the size of it does not reduce when I delete the database either programmatically

```
var request = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("databaseName");
```

or manually through "Tools-> Internet Options -> Settings (in Browsing history section) -> Caches and databases tab" and delete the entry.

As a result, it reaches the max limit and I get a QuotaExceededError or a "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" error message when I try to store a few hundred mb of data. I have set the limit to its max (1GB).

Any idea why Internet.edb size does not reduce after deleting the database?

Comment: Interestingly, [Chrome sometimes does the same thing](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=488851).